How to allow line breaks / text wrap for citations in a table using natbib
Here is an example. The actual table has more rows, this is just an example. This table will fit on the page if the Reference column would just wrap its text. I can't find a solution. I have tried breaklinks = true in the hyperref package, I have tried \usepackage{xurl}, I have used the p{} column type, all to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.
Essentially, how can I get the Reference column contents to wrap inside the cell instead of going off into the margin?
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,openany]{book} %change to oneside for final printing
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[letterpaper,
            bindingoffset=0.0in,
            left=1in,
            right=1in,
            top=1in,
            bottom=1in,
            footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[font={small,doublespacing},labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off,labelsep=period}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.25em}

%%% REFERENCES
\usepackage[numbers,square,sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
% \bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\setcitestyle{authoryear, open={(}, close={)}} %Citation-related commands
\newcommand\cites[2]{\citeauthor{#1}'s \citeyearpar{#2}}

\usepackage{multirow,textcomp}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
    citecolor=blue,
    breaklinks=true
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}[!h]
  \centering
  \footnotesize
  % \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2} % Default value: 1
  \begin{threeparttable}
      \caption{Summary of treatment performances of processes treating real wastewater with microalgal-bacterial aggregates.}
      \label{tab:LiteratCompare}
      \begin{tabular}{ccccccC{0.4in}C{0.7in}C{0.6in}C{0.6in}p{1in}}
          \toprule
          \textbf{COD Removal$^a$}    & \textbf{N Removal$^a$}      & \textbf{P Removal$^a$}      & \textbf{Duration (d)} & \textbf{HRT$^t$ (d)}         & \textbf{SRT$^v$ (d)}     & \textbf{Suppl. Aerat.} & \textbf{Waste- water Type} & \textbf{Reactor Volume (L)} & \textbf{Natural Lighting} & \textbf{Reference}                               \\ \midrule
          4\% - 95\%                  & 14\% - 100\%                & 2\% - 60\%                  & \multirow{2}*{6-30}   & \multirow{2}*{2-10}       & \multirow{2}*{2-10}   & \multirow{2}*{Yes$^{\dagger\dagger}$}         & \multirow{2}*{Municipal}       & \multirow{2}*{50}                 & \multirow{2}*{No}               & \multirow{2}*{\citet{arcila_2016}}    \\
          (593 $\pm$ 58)$^b$          & (71.2 $\pm$ 4.5)$^w$        & (15.3 $\pm$ 1.3)$^f$        &           &              &          &               &                 &                    &                  &                                     \\
          87.1\% $\pm$ 4.5\%          & 51.4\% $\pm$ 15.2\%         & 50.4\% $\pm$ 14\%           & \multirow{2}*{30}       & \multirow{2}*{10}           & \multirow{2}*{10}       & \multirow{2}*{Yes$^{\dagger\dagger}$}         & \multirow{2}*{Municipal}       & \multirow{2}*{50}                 & \multirow{2}*{Yes$^{\dagger}$}             & \multirow{2}*{\citet{arcila_2017}}           \\
          (146.7 $\pm$ 40.0)$^b$      & (1.64 $\pm$ 0.15)$^q$       & (2.8 $\pm$ 0.13)$^f$        &          &              &          &               &                 &                    &                  &                                     \\ \bottomrule
          \end{tabular}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{sidewaystable}

\bibliography{bib}

\end{document}

here are the bib items since I can't attach the bib.bib file.
@article{arcila_2016,
title = {Microalgae-bacteria aggregates: effect of the hydraulic retention time on the municipal wastewater treatment, biomass settleability and methane potential},
author = {Arcila, Juan S and Buitrón, Germán},
pages = {2862-2870},
url = {http://doi.wiley.com/10.1002/jctb.4901},
year = {2016},
month = {nov},
urldate = {2021-07-12},
journal = {Journal of Chemical Technology \& Biotechnology},
volume = {91},
number = {11},
issn = {02682575},
doi = {10.1002/jctb.4901}
}

@article{arcila_2017,
title = {Influence of solar irradiance levels on the formation of microalgae-bacteria aggregates for municipal wastewater treatment},
author = {Arcila, Juan S. and Buitrón, Germán},
pages = {190-197},
url = {https://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S2211926417303041},
year = {2017},
month = {nov},
urldate = {2021-07-12},
journal = {Algal Research},
volume = {27},
issn = {22119264},
doi = {10.1016/j.algal.2017.09.011}
}



It is because you put it in a \multirow{2}*. That should be \multirow{2}= instead.

Thanks so much!! That worked. Interestingly, when I used }={ on another column's multirow I had to include \centering in the text argument to get the content to center. Thanks again!

* means to use the width of the supplied text, so that will never do linebreaks. = means use the specified width of the column (as specified in the p{...} argument, or similar). So that wouldn't work properly in a c column. But then the text is typeset in a \parbox so any centering must be added explicitely.
Often these things are easier with the tabularray package.
